# Algebraic structures in RSA

Tags: rsa, finite-field

1. Why do we need a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) for RSA and what are the two operations in this field?
2. Why can't we have a ring or group for example? Because in a group you also have inverse elements.

Comment: What is the "field" you are speaking of regarding RSA?

Comment: The title says "Algebraic Structures" so I'm speaking of the field as an algebraic structure. -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)

Comment: Yes, I know what a field is. :) But RSA does not involve any field, or at lease not directly.

Comment: Yeah :P It's just our tutor asked why a ring or group are not sufficient for RSA. And he was talking about fields. So I assumed that we need a field for RSA. So I also don't know where we have a field, that's the reason I asked it here.

Comment: I suggest you get a new tutor.

Comment: So what algebraic structure are we using in RSA?

Answer (score 2):

RSA is not done over field. When using RSA, you rely on the fact that the adversary does not know the order of the [multiplicative group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n), i.e. he does not known the value of [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) and he is unable to compute it.

Over field, computing it is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

RSA encryption can be seen as an operation in a finite abelian group of order $\phi(n)$, with the the private exponent and public exponent being inverse elements of each other.

Then you see that $m*k*k^{-1} = m$. Of course the group operation is actually integer exponentiation with the result taken modulo some large (composite) number, $n$.

This is true, since there is an identity element $1$, for each $k$ such that $gcd(k, {\phi}(n)) = 1$ has an inverse element (each element in the group), and the group is closed because $gcd(k_0*k_1, \phi(n)) = 1$, for group elements $k_0, k_1$ (yielding another element in the group). The group is abelian simply because multiplication (of exponents) is commutative: $m^{ab} = m^{ba}$.

Comment: The nature of $*$ in this answer is confusing (at least to me), and that muddies (my perception of) the whole answer. $*$ can't be an associative group law, e.g. in $m*k*k^{-1}=m$. And $k^{-1}$ is not the inverse of $k$ with respect to the law in the group $m$ belongs to. Further, messages that have no inverse modulo $n$ still are valid RSA, and I fail to reconcile that with _"RSA encryption can be seen as an operation in a finite abelian group (..)"_.